# Modify Existing Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Please help me. I want to add field into exsting Crystal Report. once i add new field i want to filter using that field. I now how to filter but dont know how to add new field to existing crystal report.

Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 For referring to SO as a deity.

Comment: Does that make this a prayer request?

Comment: @Orbling: More of a pantheon than a deity

Comment: @skaffman: So SO is polytheist, who knew? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what tools you are using. Using the Crystal Reports IDE, I just drag a field from the data source to the report surface to add it.